# What is wrong with my approach to finding solution of these equations?

Tags: quadratic-forms

I have to find solutions $ \mathbf {(x,y)}$ where $ \mathbf x$ and $ \mathbf y$ are real numbers for the system of equations

$\mathbf {x^2-xy+y^2=21}$

$\mathbf {x^2+2xy-8y^2=0}$

what i initially did was to multiply first equation with 2 and added that to the second equation and that gave me $\mathbf {3x^2-6y^2 = 42}$ this equation for every real $ \mathbf y$ gives me a real $ \mathbf x$ , so i concluded there would be infinite solutions to the above system of equations.

However the answer is that only 4 real solutions exist and i have the solution with me , but i wanted to know why is my method of solving it wrong. Is simple algebraic addition/subtraction of functions to find their intersection not correct? or is it giving me wrong answers only in this specific case?

Comment: Every $x$ and $y$ that satisfies both equations also satisfies $3x^2-6y^2 = 42$. But not every $x$ and $y$ that satisfy that satisfy both equations at once. For example, $3\cdot8^2-6\cdot5^2=42$, but $8^2-8\cdot 5 + 5^2 = 49\ne 21$.

Comment: These two equations form a 4th degree system, which can have at most 4 solutions. What you found is not the set of solutions, but another equation which is a consequence of the first two, but not equivalent to both

Comment: Think about solving $x+y=2$ and $x-y=0$ by adding to get $x=1$. Are you done?

Comment: You can divide the equation you found by $3$ to get $x^2=14+2y^2, x=\pm \sqrt{14+2y^2}$ and plug these into one of the original equations, isolate the radical, and square to get a $4^{th}$ degree equation in $y$

Comment: Alternatively, you could eliminate $x^2$ instead of $xy$ and solve the resulting linear equation for $x$, then substitute that into one of the other equations. You'll get the same result, but won't have to deal with any radicals.

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate to multiply an equation by a non-zero constant or to add two equations together.  However, when you add them, you still need to keep two equations!  So after adding, you have $ 3 x ^ 2 - 6 y ^ 2 = 4 2 $ as one equation, but you also have either $ x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 = 21 $ or $ x ^ 2 + 2 x y - 8 y ^ 2 = 0 $ (whichever one you prefer to keep) as the other equation, and then you continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 + 2xy - 8 y^2 = 0$  is a pair of lines through the origin. The discriminant is $4 + 32 = 36$  which is a square, so that the form factors
$$ x^2 + 2xy - 8 y^2 = (x+4y)(x-2y) $$
and the lines are $x=2y$   and $x=-4y$

$x^2 - xy + y^2 = 21$ is an ellipse. In fact, as $21 = 3 \cdot 7$   we know there are integer points on the ellipse,  such as $(4,-1)$  and $(-4,1)$ which are on one of the lines.  The other pair of poin ts need extra work and probably square root signs,  when $x=2y$  and $x^2 - xy + y^2 = 21$  we are stuck with $4y^2 -2 y^2 + y^2 = 21$ or $3 y^2 = 21,$  or $y = \pm \sqrt 7.$ Thus $(2 \sqrt 7, \sqrt 7)$   and $(-2 \sqrt 7, -\sqrt 7)$

Comment: Why exactly can we conclude the existence of integer points purely from $21 = 3\cdot7$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog  any product of primes $3$  and any $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$  can be written (primitively) as $u^2 + 3 v^2.$  Or, same numbers,  $x^2 - xy + y^2 .$   Similar fact  for $u^2  - 5v^2$  and $x^2 +xy - y^2$  where now the primes are $\pm 1 \pmod 5$

Answer (score 0):

I've graphed all three equations in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=graph%20x%5E2-xy%2By%5E2%3D21%20and%20x%5E2%2B2xy-8y%5E2%3D0%20and%203x%5E2-6y%5E2%3D42) for you - the blue and red lines are the given equations, while the yellow is the one you derived.

Notice that all three equations meet at the same four points. What this means is that for the four points which form the solution set of the original equation, the third equation is also true - it's *necessary* that any point that satisfies both of the given equations also satisfies the derived one - but it's not *sufficient*, meaning that not every point on $3x^2-6y^2=42$ is guaranteed to be in the solution set.

Comment: Thank you. so i can say that if the first curve is A and second is B then any equation of the form pA + qB = 0 would give me family of curves which pass through the intersection of A and B. right?